# how to setTag for int Array in Android

Tags: android, arrays

I'm learning Android and can be appropriate not my question , but I 'd appreciate any help

I'm trying to make a memory game , I have two arrays named imgBack is ImageView Array of buttons and an int Array of images called imgFace

I need to setTag() to int Array called imgFace

When I try to do setTag() to the int Array (imagesFace) is not possible because it belongs to the VIEW and if I make the Array of imgFace to ImageView Array I can not do setImageResource() to cardImg (becouse is required int)

I add a section of code

Thank you again for your answer

```
for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
            imgBack[i].setImageResource(R.drawable.icon);
            final int imagesFace = imgFace[position[i] - 1];
            final ImageView cardImg = imgBack[i];
            //cardImg.setTag(i);

            cardImg.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    cardImg.setImageResource(imagesFace);
                    ImageView cardThatWasClicked = (ImageView) v;
                    int cardId = (int) cardThatWasClicked.getTag();
                    counter++;
                    if (counter % 2 == 0) {//b
                        cardB = cardId;
                        if (cardB == cardA) {
                            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "match!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "NOT match!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    } else {//a
                        if (cardA != -1) {
                            imgBack[cardA].setImageResource(R.drawable.icon);
                            imgBack[cardB].setImageResource(R.drawable.icon);
                        }
                        cardA = cardId;
                    }

                }
            });
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can write:

```
cardImg.setTag(new Integer(i));
```

And get it like:

```
int i = (int) cardImg.getTag();
```

**Note:** `setTag` method takes its input argument as of type `Object`. In Java `int`, `float`, ... are primitive types and do not extend Java `Object` base class. However `Integer`, `Float`, ... are equivalent classes that extend base `Object` class.

Comment: Hi ! thank you for you quick reply! But how can I do setTag() to the imagesFace? If I do setTag to cardImg He gives me a card ID and not the picture ID

Comment: @joD As I've looked your codes, `imageFace` is of type `int` and integers cannot hold an additional variable. You could instead use a class field to save your stuff or somewhere else. Anyway, `setTag` is only for Android View class and its derivations. For other objects you can either use class fields or extending that object to add this capability. If something is unclear, please let me know to explain more.